# NameError: name 'named_entity_extractor' is not defined

Tags: python, nlp

```
import sys, os
parent = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath("cobaie"))
sys.path.append(parent + '/../../mitielib')

from mitie import *
```

- The training process for a binary relation detector requires a `MITIE NER` object as
- input.  So we load the saved `NER` model first.

`ner = named_entity_extractor("../../MITIE-models/english/ner_model.dat")`

Answer (score 0):

Please check for the following:

Define the class before you use it.

You need to pass self as the first argument to all instance methods.